# There's problem in accessing files inside HTTPTrigger in azure function app after deployment?

Tags: python-3.x, azure-functions

azure function platform = Linux

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, firefox_profile= fp, executable_path=‘HttpTrigger/geckodriver’)
```

unable to find path present in the same folder HTTPtrigger

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the function directory, you need function context to get the property. This information is exposed by `func.Context`, further more information you could refer to this wiki doc: [Python on Functions V2](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Retrieving-information-about-the-currently-running-function#python-on-functions-v2-or-higher).

After introducing `context: func.Context`, you could use `context.function_directory` to get the `FunctionDirectory`.

And if you are using v1 function, all language could get it from the environment variable `EXECUTION_CONTEXT_FUNCTIONNAME`.

Comment: We are using v12

Comment: I'm saying function version, what do you mean v12?

Comment: Yes, this issue has been fixed.

Comment: @shra_，if this could help you, you could accept it as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Your answer didn't helped us in fixing this !

Comment: @shra_，Why did you say this issue has been fixed? Did you already have the solution, if yes you could edit it and publish to help the community if other has this question and mark it as the answer.